# SQL column merge with conditions and without duplicates

Tags: sql, join, duplicates, multiple-conditions

Trying to combine 2 tables into 1 results table without having duplicate entries.
Conditions are:
1. For each t1name look for each days in t2date, and if there is 1 in t2update, use that info. If there is no 1, then use the 0 row.
2. If the t1name doesn't exist in t2name, create it with the t1date, and set t2update as 0.

Here the are tables examples:

```
| t1name | t1date     | t1department |
| ------ | ---------- | ------------ |
| name 1 | 2000.01.01 | tlc          | 
| name 1 | 2000.01.01 | tlc          |
| name 2 | 2000.01.04 | non-tlc      |
| name 3 | 2000.01.04 | non-tlc      |
| name 4 | 2000.01.04 | tlc          |
| name 5 | 2000.01.04 | tlc          |
| name 6 | 2000.01.04 | tlc          |
| name 7 | 2000.01.04 | tlc          |
```

[Table 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tLdeW.png)

```
| t2name | t2update | t2date       |
| ------ | -------- | ------------ |
| name 1 | 1        | 2000.01.01   |
| name 1 | 0        | 2000.01.02   | 
| name 1 | 1        | 2000.01.02   | 
| name 2 | 1        | 2000.01.04   | 
| name 2 | 0        | 2000.01.04   | 
| name 2 | 0        | 2000.01.09   | 
| name 3 | 0        | 2000.01.09   | 
| name 3 | 1        | 2000.01.05   | 
| name 4 | 0        | 2000.01.03   |
```

[Table 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yjQWv.png)

```
| rname  | rupdate | rdate        |
| ------ | ------- | ------------ |
| name 1 | 1       | 2000.01.01   |
| name 1 | 1       | 2000.01.02   | 
| name 2 | 1       | 2000.01.04   | 
| name 3 | 0       | 2000.01.02   | 
| name 3 | 1       | 2000.01.05   | 
| name 4 | 0       | 2000.01.03   | 
| name 5 | 0       | 2000.01.09   | 
| name 6 | 0       | 2000.01.09   | 
| name 7 | 0       | 2000.01.09   |
```

[Results table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GRGtJ.png)

Currently using following:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW "rtable" AS 
(
   SELECT DISTINCT
      ((CASE WHEN (t2.t2updates) > 0) AND (MAX(t1.t1date))) THEN name
    , t1.date
    , t1.t1department
    , t2.updates 
FROM (table1 t1
LEFT JOIN table2 t2 on (t2.t2name = t1.t1name))
GROUP BY 
    , t1.date
    , t1.t1department
    , t2.updates
ORDER BY t1.t1name ASC
)
```

And the results return duplicate values per day. For single t1name and t1date have both entries for 1 and 0. Need the outcome in a specific way so it I can do KPI on the updates of the VMs.

Comment: Please provide sample input, expected outcome etc. as text here in your question, use formatting to show the data as tables. Don't add images or links. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277716/how-can-i-create-a-table-in-a-post

Comment: Thank you for the prompt response. tables used and desired outcome table have been provided.

Comment: I don't understand which logic should be applied there. Why on earth should for example the last 3 rows of the expected result table have this date? Those names have the date 2000.01.04, not 2000.01.09 in table1 and in table2 those names don't appear. Please describe precisely the entire logic. Your description is much too vague.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After simplifying the approach, and plenty of trials and error, simple right join did the job

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW "rtable" AS 
(
   SELECT
      t2.name
    , t2.date
    , t1.t1department
    , t2.updates 
FROM 
    (table1 t1
Right JOIN table2 t2 on (t2.t2name = t1.t1name) AND (t2.date = t1.date)))
)
```

Comment: To add to the answer. Data source needed some cleaning to avoid duplicates for t2.t2name.